# How to add UEFI boot entry for a removable drive that persists between devices?

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning

I use two UEFI utilities on a regular basis and would like to boot them from the same USB. How can I get multiple entries in the boot menu for the same USB? I'm avoiding using a middleman like a software bootloader, as that adds extra boot time.

I'm looking for a way to achieve this effect on the USB drive itself, so I can boot one utility by default, or enter the boot menu to select the other utility.

I tried creating multiple partitions on one USB but the bootloader is stupid and just grabs the first \EFI\BOOT\BOOT*.EFI it sees. If I rename the EFI folder on the first partition to noEFI, it will boot from the second partition, but it won't recognize that there are two partitions.

I'm sure I'm configuring something wrong – the UEFI bootloader is supposed to scan every partition for \EFI\BOOT\BOOT*.EFI, right?

Comment: I see you have not been helped. Have you worked out the situation? There is a popular software called __YUMI__ it "is a lightweight and portable application" it can be found here: https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/YUMI.shtml A Good article  for you might be here "How To Install Multiple Bootable Operating Systems On One USB" an article written in June of 2020 https://techviral.net/create-multiboot-usb/   Hope I helped, good luck.

Comment: Currently using a boot manager (rEFInd) and I have my USB in three FAT32 partitions to keep the tools separate for easier maintenance. rEFInd adds 3 seconds or so to boot time so it isn't ideal, but it's highly configurable and allows scripted boots which I'm sure will come in handy.

Comment: I've tried YUMI but it confuses me - you're meant to select an image, but you also have to provide the ISO. I assume this means YUMI tailors its configuration to your ISO selection behind the scenes, but I don't see a way to configure it for custom or non-ISO OEM tools like Lenovo's U1 tool.
Both those links are purple to me, haha. I think what I was ultimately looking for is not possible - it appears that [the UEFI Spec](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202.8B%20May%202020.pdf) (p. 500) explicitly forbids removable media from having multiple automatic boot entries.

Answer (score 3):

**Removable media devices cannot have more than one boot entry added to the UEFI boot menu.**

The boot manager finds the first EFI partition that contains \EFI\BOOT\BOOT{machine type short name}.EFI before moving to the next device, so any additional partitions, however properly formatted, are ignored.

Haven't got a clue why it's designed that way.

---

[UEFI Spec v2.8 (May 2020)](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202.8B%20May%202020.pdf#page=573):

> For removable media devices there must be only one UEFI-compliant system partition, and that partition must contain an UEFI-defined directory in the root directory. The directory will be named EFI. All OS loaders and applications will be stored in a subdirectory below EFI called BOOT. There must only be one executable EFI image for each supported processor architecture in the BOOT directory. For removable media to be bootable under EFI, it must be built in accordance with the rules laid out in Section3.5.1.1. This guarantees that there is only one image that can be automatically loaded from a removable media device by the EFI Boot Manager. Any additional EFI executables must be in directories other than BOOT.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the update, yes, you have to have one ore more .ISO files to be configured.